# A Go slice holds a reference to a subsection of an array or just a single element?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

[Golang blog about slices and arrays](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

> think of a slice as a little data structure with two elements: a length and a pointer to an element of an array.

Little bewildered by verbiage saying: '...pointer to an ELEMENT of an array.' That would only be the case if it was a slice with len() of 1, right?

I believe the blog post may have meant to say that it was a pointer to a 'subsection' of an array, right?

Comment: Right. I was just reviewing about concept of 'slice header.' Tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a pointer to the *first* slice element in the backing array. I bet this wording comes from Go language C background :)

Comment: Yes, that makes it more clear about it pointing to AN element in array. Ok.